# Multiple Instances of ClickOnce app

Tags: installation, clickonce

Some background to my problem...

We are currently using ClickOnce to deploy part of our solution which was working a treat until we encountered a scenario where we are now required to have multiple instances of our application installed on the same PC. We are able to achieve this internally and have this working perfectly as we know what instances we have so our build process will update AssemblyName to include the instance name before publishing the installer, this means we are able to have multiple instances on our PCs internally (ie, test, live and demo etc).

Our external deployment process is slightly different, we take one of the ClickOnce installers created in our build (along with all our other components that make up our application) and as the ClickOnce installer is deployed on a server we update the app.config along with the manifest files and resign so they now have client specific details. If a client chooses to have multiple instances of our product installed the ClickOnce will now fail when a second instance is installed on a desktop PC as all instances share the same assemble name.

So finally to the question, does anyone know of a way to update the manifest etc after the clickonce package has been created to allow multiple instances to be installed? We could go down the route of building many clickOnce installers but I dont think this will really work for us, is there perhaps an alternative to ClickOnce which provides a similar upgrade experience for non-admin users?

Hopefully someone will be able to share their experiences and help me resolve this.

Thanks in advance
Doug

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of another technology that allows such a simple auto update process. So sticking with ClickOnce... [I think this link might be useful](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/04/22/clickonce-installing-multiple-versions-concurrently/). It explains what you need to do to have the same app installed twice. Essentially changing the assembly name and product name should do it.

Hope that helps.
Greg

Comment: I was aware of this and this is what we are doing successfully internally as we know what we want to build and deploy but this doesn't really work in our client situation as we have the scenario of multiple live and uat instances and these aren't in our control and not known until the last moment ie long after we build.